# Why Does the Last Print Statement Not Require The Variable symbols In It?

Tags: python

Trying to understand why the print statement of the outer for loop, does not require the variable symbol inside of its parenthesis.  This program ex is from a Python tutorial video by channel Bro Code.  It draws a rectangle based off of a certain amount of rows, columns, and symbol the user chooses.

```
rows = int(input("How many rows?: "))
columns = int(input("How many columns?: "))
symbol = input("Enter a symbol to use: ")

for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(columns): 
        print(symbol, end="")  
    print() # <------ (why is symbols not needed in () of print() )
```

Comment: Because it's not printing any variables, it's just printing a newline.

Comment: Hmm.  I'm not getting it.  So let's see if I have this right.  The inner loop is doing the printing of the symbol, while the outer loop just defines the rows and prints a new line up to the defined row number by the user?

Comment: Yes. The inner loop uses `end=""` to print on the same line. `print()` just puts a newline between each row.

Comment: Ah okay.  I get it now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That is just for a new line. By default, `print()`'s `end` parameter has a default value `'\n'`.

Simply putting `print()` will only add a new line.

That is what it is doing here.

```
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(columns): 
        print(symbol, end="")  
    print() # <------ (Adding a new line)
```

If you don't put `print()`, all your output will be on 1 line. So prevent that, `print` is there